# Display each record on a separate page?

Tags: crystal-reports, record

[image]Crystal report not showing my records one by one it shows each record on separate page any suggestion ?

Comment: R u using the group ??????

Comment: Plz post ur code for more details...........

Comment: no its just simple report no groups

Comment: plz put image of the ur .rpt file..........

Comment: @ChetanSanghani uploaded snapshot of report please have look and give any suggestion .

Comment: Where is the uploaded image ?

Comment: Check below the question heading

Comment: there is nothing below the heading.....

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7KDew.jpg

Comment: There r problem in viewing ur image........But Put ur Heading in page header and field in the detail section

Comment: u can take a group...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close up your sections so that there is not as much space between them.  If the fields need to "grow" go into the field properties and set it to grow as needed.

Comment: +1 The details section is huge and is printing too much white space per record. The fields in this section need to be moved up and then the whole section needs to be made smaller.